# Unable to highlight/copy text in iPhone Safari on mobile site

Tags: iphone, css, safari

I have a mobile site which I'm testing on the iPhone, and unlike most other sites, I'm not able to hold my finger on the screen to get the 'copy' menu to appear (with the draggable handles to select an area to copy). Nothing happens at all on my site.

I've tried adding the following to my style sheet but it hasn't made any difference:

-webkit-user-select: text;

I should also state that I have the following also in my style sheet and within the page head:

-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;

I've got these as I didn't want the content to be scalable, and just wanted the content to span 100% of the device width.

Would the implementation of any of the above be causing the lack of selectable text on the site? Out of interest, I tried the flickr mobile website which also is not scalable and uses 100% of the device width like my site, and that also doesn't seem to come up with the draggable/select area for copying when you hold your finger on some text.

Does anyone have any idea why this is or how I can make the text content (or any content actually) selectable for copying/pasting?

Thanks

Comment: Can we get a link to the site?

Comment: same issue... did you solve the problem?

Comment: Repeating what @ceejayoz said... do you have a link to the site?

Comment: Yes, it's http://www.goneboarding.co.uk/mobile/

Comment: thats strange... it works on my 3g ... are you sure your holding your finger down long enough?

Comment: Works for me too.  Running on an iPhone 4S with 5.1.1.  No problems copying or pasting anything.

Comment: Did you have a click handler somewhere on an ancestor element of the text nodes you were trying to select?

Comment: Does not work for me too. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

are there any elements that may be obscuring the items by overlaying them, etc? a z-indexing issue, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No there isn't. It's a pretty straight forward layout really too. Very confused :(